# jQuery dialog: Open position at mouse position. Doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, firefox, mouseevent

I am setting jQuery's UI dialog position to:

```
my: "left",
at: "left",
of: event,
```

Now this works in all browsers apart from Firefox.

What should the '`event`' be to work cross browser?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AZFnb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 'event' to 'e'.

When you set up mouse event you assigned event to e

```
$("button").click(function(e) {...
```

Updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AZFnb/1/

Comment: Ah you're right. my actual button click function was e instead of event. Thanks